# Advanced Conditional Formatting Breaks SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer

A little background information. I'm working with SharePoint Designer 2010 and am editing the NewFormReplacement (a Replacement form for the Default NewForm) to get entries into a list on the business divisions SharePoint Site.

I'm using the advanced conditional formatting by selecting the entire row for the form and applying the IfHasRights() function. From everything I have read and seen online, this is the general consensus of how to manipulate forms based on user permissions. The resulting line of code makes sense (shown below).

```
    <xsl:if test="ddwrt:IfHasRights(2048)">
<tr>
<td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
<H3 class="ms-standardheader">
<nobr>Delete</nobr></H3></td>
<td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff1{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Delete"
    __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff1',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Delete')}" /><SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff1description{$Pos}" FieldName="Delete" ControlMode="New" />
</td></tr></xsl:if>
```

However, when I save the change and reload the form the site throws the following error:

> *Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML
>   editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists,
>   contact your Web server administrator.*
>
> *Correlation ID:73f6c69c-c964-00f0-1589-f70ea3480689*

In the end, I didn't end up needing to hide/display fields based on user permission, however I'm hoping to sate my curiousity as to what causes for this might be? Is it something along the lines of the SharePoint setup on the server? Could it be an issues with SharePoint itself? Has anyone else even had this happen to them?

Comment: Check the logs and look for the correlation id. It can shed some light.